# What is it I am doing wrong using `\tl_case:Nn ...`?

Tags: expl3

When using document command arguments for case distinctions I routinely have been using the `\str_case:nn` function, which works fine as is evident from the output of the `\myStrCase` command. When attempting to use the `\tl_case:Nn` function instead, by loading the argument into a `_tl` type variable, things go miserably wrong. The variable seems to be loaded with the correct value, and is then flagged as correct as far as the `\tl_case:Nn` function is concerned, but the corresponding code is not executed. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations,log-functions]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_Aux_tl
\NewDocumentCommand\myStrCase{O{emph}m}
  {
    \str_case:nnTF {#1}
      {
        {emph}{\textit{#2}}
        {Emph}{\textbf{\textit{#2}}}
        {uline}{\underline{#2}}
      }
      {}
      {!~ERROR:~parameter~\#1~=~#1~invalid}
  }  %  \myStrCase
\NewDocumentCommand\myTlCase{O{emph}m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_rn_Aux_tl {#1}
checking~what~was~passed:~\l_rn_Aux_tl \\
    \tl_case:NnTF \l_rn_Aux_tl
      {
        emph {\textit{#2}}
        Emph {\textbf{\textit{#2}}}
        uline {\underline{#2}}
      }
      {parameter~\#1~=~#1~valid}
      {!~ERROR:~parameter~\#1~=~#1~invalid}
  }  %  \myTlCase
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
\subsection{using str\_case:}
  \myStrCase{Hi There}\\
  \myStrCase[emph]{Hi There}\\
  \myStrCase[Emph]{Hi There}\\
  \myStrCase[uline]{Hi There}\\
  \myStrCase[xxx]{Hi There}
\subsection{using tl\_case:}
  \myTlCase[emph]{Hi There}\\
  \myTlCase[xxx]{Hi There}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation (interface3) already contains your answer:

```
\tl_case:NnTF <test token list variable>
{
<token list variable case1> {<code case1>}
<token list variable case2> {<code case2>}
...
<token list variable casen> {<code casen>}
}
{<true code>}
{<false code>}
```

You will find "token list variable" and not "token list" therein. Hence you are asked to provide one token (a variable/N-type argument). So to use this construction you would need to save your options into variables and use these within `\tl_case`.